# Windows c# WPF Annimate Canvas Size

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, canvas

Before I ask my question let me try to explain what I am trying to accomplish. In my WPF window I have a button in the middle of the window. When that button is clicked I want to have a sub menu slide out from the button and expand with sub menu buttons.

If you think I might be approaching this the wrong way please, I'm open to suggestions. I am very new to WPF as I'm trying to transition from WinForms.

From my searches I have found how to use storyboards or doublAnimation to resize buttons and shapes. I so far have not been able to find how to do this with a canvas. I have found how to store the canvas outside of the window ans slide it in, but i want it to collapse into the trigger button.

The closet example I think I have found was this article from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

I am currently just using that entire example from MSDN to just attempt to learn the basics of animating canvas size. I thought once I learn how to do that in a simple environment, then I could apply it to my application.

I modified the XML to point towards my canvas (name="Can")  but I am returned an error

> "Can is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation project."

My project is a copy/paste of the WPF example on the MSDN webpage linked above. I have only modified the DoubleAnimation element of the first button to this

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Can"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Can.Width)"
                             To="500" 
                             Duration="0:0:3" 
                             AutoReverse="true" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Any Help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Width)"`.  There is not a `Can` type in WPF with a `Width` property.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. Such a silly error. I misunderstood the syntax. I thought it was ("name.property"). Thank you very much!